# jquery is not working onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

on click id="check_user" alert is not working .and this is my code.

```
<html>
    <script>
        $("#check_user").click(function(){
        alert("good");
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <label name="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="log_user_email" placeholder="example@example.com" />
        <label name="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="log_password" placeholder="*********"/>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="check_user"  style="cursor:pointer;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What console error do you have?

Comment: Did you add Jquery library into it?

Comment: Works for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/17jkp30x/

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar because you have set jsfiddle set to execute script after onload. Set it to something else and it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have added the jquery library, You need to attach the event when DOM is loaded.i.e. on DOM ready event:

```
$(function(){//document ready function
 $("#check_user").click(function(){
  alert("good");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery script you've written is inside 'script' tag. Nice !
But the whole script should either be inside 'head' tag or inside 'body' tag. ;) 3:)

Answer (score 0):

use `on` method for adding event for dynamically  element added
and wrap the jquery code inside the `$(document).ready()` method

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check_user").on('click', function(evt) {
      alert("good");
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



  <label name="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="log_user_email" placeholder="example@example.com" />
  <label name="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="log_password" placeholder="*********" />
  <button type="button" id="check_user">login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you haven't shown your entire code, and your code appears valid, I can only assume that you have not added the jQuery library before adding that script tag. And you should also wrap your code within the jQuery ready function `$(document).ready();` especially seeing that your code appears before the `body` tag which means the DOM content would not have completely downloaded at the time the script is executed.

In summary, make sure you added included the jQuery library before your script.

Also wrap your code with `$(document).ready();` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#check_user").click(function() {
        alert("good");
    });
});
```

Comment: how to add jQuery library

Comment: You can include the library as a script before the code you've written. e.g. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: thanks can you say ,is there any library function for calling $.ajax().since my $.ajax is not working

Comment: There's no ajax related code in the code you added. Why would you want to use $.ajax() ?